# Creating a list of lists containing specific values of a list in python

Tags: python, list, range

I Have a list A:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
```

I want to code a function that will return a list of lists B:

```
B=[[4,5,6],[10,11,12],[16,17,18]]
```

I tried this:

```
def listing():
    A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
    ans= [A[i:len(A)] for i in range(0, len(A), 3)]
    return ans
```

But it gives me a very long and incorrect output, how could I fix this?

Comment: `A[i:len(A)]` should be `A[i:i+3]`

Comment: It should be `range(3, len(A), 6)` in order to get every other chunk.

Comment: @Wondercricket that seperates the entire list into lists of 3, but I need only the specific sections I showed in list B, thank you for your help though!

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar

Comment: `list(zip(*[iter(A)]*3))[1::2]`

Comment: This is simply chunking, taking alternating chunks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python [idiom](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) for making x length sub lists from a list of `zip(*[iter(A)]*3)` and then just slice that to get every other one:

```
>>> list(zip(*[iter(A)]*3))[1::2]
[(4, 5, 6), (10, 11, 12), (16, 17, 18)]
```

If you want a list of lists rather than a list of tuples:

```
>>> [list(sl) for sl in list(zip(*[iter(A)]*3))[1::2]]
[[4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12], [16, 17, 18]]
```

Another way is to enumerate the sublists and skip the even numbered enumerations:

```
>>> [sl for ind,sl in enumerate(A[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(A), 3)) if ind % 2]
[[4, 5, 6], [10, 11, 12], [16, 17, 18]]
```